# Does a split for a XmlInputFormat always contain the starting and ending tags of an element?

Tags: xml, hadoop

I'm wondering how an Xml file with several splits is handled.
Who takes care of putting the starting and ending tags of an Xml element in the same split ?
Is it the responsability of XmlInputFormat or of the program that creates the Xml file on HDFS ?

Best,
Kimchi

Answer (score 0):

XMLInputFormat requires you to specify start and end tag's using `xmlinput.start` and `xmlinput.end` respectively. Once, you have specified the start and end tags for your xml then XMLInputForamt's RecordReader will be able to figure out the record boundaries.

For reference take a look at code for [XMLInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java).

So, the program that creates the XML file in HDFS does not have to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was confused because I didn't realize that an InputSplit ia a "logical" split and not a physical one (i.e. reading bytes from the HDFS blocks).